# need a solution to increase decrease font size on website

Tags: javascript

I am trying to add a option on one of my Website where user can change font size. and i found a video on youtube (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MOgBW3WKeCc).  but i don't know Why my script is not working.

here is my codes:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {

            $('#fontincrease').click(function() {
                modifyFontSize('increase');
            });
            $('#fontdecrease').click(function() {
                modifyFontSize('decrease');
            });
            $('#fontreset').click(function() {
                modifyFontSize('reset');
            });

            function modifyFontSize(flag) {
                var divElement = $('#entrypbody');
                var currentFontSize = parseInt(divElement.css('font-size'));

                if (flag =='increase') {
                    currentFontSize +=2;
                }; else if (flag ='decrease') {
                    currentFontSize -=2;
                }; else currentFontSize = 15;

                divElement.css('font-size', currentFontSize);
            }
        });
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        .paragraph {
            font-size: 15px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    Font Size: <a id="fontincrease" href="#">increase</a> <a id="fontdecrease" href="#">decrease</a> <a id="fontreset" href="#">reset</a>
</div>
<div id="entrypbody" class="paragraph" >
    <ul>
        <li>unorderd list 1</li>
        <li>unorderd list 2</li>
        <li>unorderd list 3</li>
        <li>unorderd list 4</li>
    </ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

can any one help me to get out of this problem??

Comment: Note that every  major browser now has this feature built in to the browser itself, so maybe this isn't even a feature you need to focus on.

Comment: As for why your script may not be working, we need more info. Namely, what is the error(s) you are getting in your JavaScript console. I also have to ask the obvious: are you actually loading jQuery?

Comment: Remove the obsolete semi-colons after the closing braces in your if-statement and add the missing ones in the else statement. And fix the if/else statment - you're assigning, not comparing. And a [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/) would be nice in the future. ;-)

Comment: yes i am trying to loading jQuery..

Comment: I don't see a link to jQuery anywhere in the code you are showing.

Comment: Thanks "DA" its working... i just forgot to add this link....

Answer (score 0):

There are too much semi-colons in your if statement. Here is the good way :

```
if (flag == 'increase') {
    currentFontSize +=2;
} else if (flag == 'decrease') {
    currentFontSize -=2;
} else {
    currentFontSize = 15;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to 3 errors in your code , read the comments blow.

1,2) you should not use semicolon between if statement blocks

**See this:** http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_if_else.asp

3) You should use **==**  to compare instead of **=** , as **=** used to set a value to a var .

**See this:** http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_operators.asp

```
 if (flag =='increase') {
    currentFontSize +=2;
     }; else if (flag ='decrease') { // 2 errors here (you should delete the semicolon) then (you should use == to compare instead of = ) 
     currentFontSize -=2;
     }; else currentFontSize = 15; // 1 error here (you should delete the semicolon)
```

**After editing**

```
if (flag =='increase') {
    currentFontSize +=2;
     } else if (flag =='decrease') { // edited 
     currentFontSize -=2;
     } else currentFontSize = 15; // edited
```